# How to assert types using library typing?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Is there a way to assert type descriptions at run time?

*wishful thinking*:

```py
import typing

def work(hours: int, place: str, fruit: List[str]):
    typing.assert(hours, int)
    typing.assert(place, str)
    typing.assert(fruit, List[str])
    ...
```

[typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) library

Comment: Do you want the annotation to *implicitly* mean a runtime assertion, or do you want an *explicit* assertion using manually supplied types? Are you looking for ``assert isinstance(hours, int)``? Note that any non-trivial check such as ``isinstance(fruit, List[str])`` would be painfully slow due to being O(n) or worse.

Comment: Are you asking how to check the type of an object? `typing` is for *type annotations*, not for runtime type checking

Comment: `List[str]` is not a `type` , it is a type annotation. You'd have to write the logic yourself, or use a library that has implemented this already, like `pydantic`, note, checking a type annotation like `List[str]` would be really inefficient

Comment: So instead, you should probably use a third-party static type checker like `mypy`